# python NameError: global name

Tags: python, function, pygame

Hello i keep getting this error when trying to run the function and,
Pick a color in this case it's pink.

```
import pygame
```

import sys
import menu
import rgbcolors
from pygame.locals import *
from rgbcolors import rgbcolor

def main():

```
# start screen
pygame.init()
screen1 = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 400))

# Fill background
background = pygame.Surface(screen1.get_size())
pygame.draw.line(screen1, (255, 0, 0), (230, 230), (100, 211), 4)
background = background.convert()
background.fill((0, 0,0))


# Displaying text
font = pygame.font.Font(None, 36)
text = font.render("Alien", 23, ((rgbcolor(pink))))
textpos = text.get_rect()
textpos.centerx = background.get_rect().centerx
background.blit(text, textpos)

screen1.blit(background, (0, 0))
pygame.display.flip()

while 1:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            return
    screen1.blit(background, (0, 0))
    pygame.display.flip()
    pygame.time.get_ticks()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

and this is my rgbcolor function.

```
def rgbcolor(color):
    red = (255, 0, 0)
    green = (0, 255, 0)
    blue = (0, 0, 255)
    darkBlue = (0, 0, 128)
    white = (255, 255, 255)
    black = (0, 0, 0)
    pink = (255, 200, 200)

pass
```

error code.

```
    C:\Python27\python.exe C:/Users/Peter/PycharmProjects/game1/game.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Peter/PycharmProjects/game1/game.py", line 44, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:/Users/Peter/PycharmProjects/game1/game.py", line 27, in main
    text = font.render("Alien", 23, ((rgbcolor(pink))))
NameError: global name 'pink' is not defined

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Have you considered sharing the entire error message with us?

Comment: C:\Python27\python.exe C:/Users/Peter/PycharmProjects/game1/game.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Peter/PycharmProjects/game1/game.py", line 43, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:/Users/Peter/PycharmProjects/game1/game.py", line 26, in main
    text = font.render("Alien", 23, ((rgbcolor(pink))))
NameError: global name 'pink' is not defined

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: You have a function that does nothing but define local variables and throw them away, with a parameter that's never used, called with an argument that's an undefined variable. I think you would benefit from reviewing a tutorial.

Comment: would you suggest one? thanks man

Comment: The [official Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/index.html) is excellent.

Comment: You could do it without function - as global constants (with prefered UPPER_CASE names)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

try with this:

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *


def rgbcolor(color):
    colors = {'red': (255, 0, 0), 'green': (0, 255, 0), 'blue': (0, 0, 255),
              'darkBlue': (0, 0, 128), 'white': (255, 255, 255), 'black': (0, 0, 0),
              'pink': (255, 200, 200)}
    return colors[color]


def main():
    # start screen
    pygame.init()
    screen1 = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 400))

    # Fill background
    background = pygame.Surface(screen1.get_size())
    pygame.draw.line(screen1, (255, 0, 0), (230, 230), (100, 211), 4)
    background = background.convert()
    background.fill((0, 0, 0))

    # Displaying text
    font = pygame.font.Font(None, 36)
    text = font.render("Alien", 23, rgbcolor('pink'))
    textpos = text.get_rect()
    textpos.centerx = background.get_rect().centerx
    background.blit(text, textpos)
    screen1.blit(background, (0, 0))
    pygame.display.flip()
    while 1:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                return
        screen1.blit(background, (0, 0))
        pygame.display.flip()
        pygame.time.get_ticks()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: That works but im trying to make it a function is it possible to do?

Comment: @PeterEvans What is the task that the function would do?

Comment: @PeterEvans update my solution